# Uncaught TypeError: ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would really appreciate another pair of eyes to review why this issue persists.

Basically, a component does some check with validation functions imported from another file

```
...
const {emailField, phoneFieldUS, postalCodeField} = validators;

class ReturnForm extends React.Component {

...

    formHasAnyErrors = () => {
        console.log("phoneFieldUS type ", typeof phoneFieldUS)
        console.log("postalCodeField type ", typeof postalCodeField)

        const zipCodeValid = postalCodeField(form.contactInfo.postalCode);
        const emailValid = emailField(form.contactInfo.email);
        const mobileValid = phoneFieldUS(form.contactInfo.mobile);
        if (!zipCodeValid || !emailValid || !mobileValid) {
            return true;
        }

        return Object.values(errors.contactInfo).find(el => !!el);
    };

...

}
```

And the validators imported looks like this:

```
exports.default = exports.validators = exports.validatorFactory = exports.statuses = exports.layouts = void 0;

const validatorFactory = (test, pass = () => {}, fail = () => {}) => {
  return value => {
    const validValue = test(value);

    if (validValue === true) {
      pass();
    } else {
      fail();
    }

    return validValue;
  };
};


exports.validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
const validators = {
emailField: validatorFactory(value => {
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(value); // eslint-disable-line max-len
  }),
  postalCodeField: validatorFactory(value => { 
    return ((value.length === 5 && /^\d+$/.test(value)) ^ (value.length === 6 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(value)))
  }),
  emptyField: validatorFactory(value => value.length > 0 && !/^\s*$/.test(value)),
  phoneFieldUS: validatorFactory(value => /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$/.test(value))
};
exports.validators = validators;
```

What I absolutely don't understand is

```
        console.log("phoneFieldUS type ", typeof phoneFieldUS) // prints function
        console.log("postalCodeField type ", typeof postalCodeField) // prints undefined
```

Hence every time the ReturnForm component is complaining about `Uncaught TypeError: postalCodeField is not a function`

Like how?????? They're both defined almost the same way?????? Please tell me if I'm missing something, any help appreciated!

Comment: It's defined when I tried. Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: The only mistake I can see with the above code is that you're destructuring `emailField` from `validators`, when it's `undefined`.

Comment: So it worked on your end? I copy-pasted the exact thing, just removed unrelated parts, and it was 100% imported with that source.

Comment: Yes, it worked on my side.

Comment: @fubar May I ask for more details on the destructuring part please? I didn't see anything wrong with the `emailField`

Comment: You named it `emptyField` in validators and used it as `emailField` in the other file.

Comment: @technophyle Thanks for elaborating! Please don't worry about that though, it's used in other components. And there's also an `emailField` in validator , just removed in above context.

Comment: @Kei - it's as technophyle said, you defined the validator property `emptyField`, but attempted to destructure a property called `emailField`.

Comment: @fubar Got it. That's my editing mistake, `emailField` is actually defined where `emptyField` is for some other components, I've edited the post to reduce the confusion. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kei My thought is that you have somehow not using the exact same code as you posted here. Try `console.log`ging your `validtors` before exporting, and right after importing it.

Comment: @technophyle  sounds like a good plan! Thanks, I’ll try doing that and see how it works

Comment: @technophyle hey sorry for the late reply, it does seem like after import it's still `undefined` rather than a function. Thank you for the suggestion! I'll look into this more.